# Program is not running in python

Tags: python, if-statement

My `else` and `else if` statements are not working. Every time it is showing incorrect syntax, whether I run it in shell or in file.

```
>>> num = 6
>>> if num == 4:
        print("no is 4")
        else:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: can you post your code.

Comment: I suggest you go and learn about Python indentation, it's rather intrinsic to getting the language working. Then it should be obvious that your code is not indented properly.

Comment: Please copy-paste your code, not a picture. Anyway the comment just above pretty much answers your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your indentation is bad :

```
if num == 4:
    print("num is 4")
else:
    print("num is not 4")
```

Comment: Exactly. This indentation is not wrong. It is bad.

Answer (score -2):

The following code will print True to the console.

```
num = 6
if num is 6:
    print(True);
else:
    print(False);
```

Comment: This answer is wrong, I am afraid. You really can use the == operator comparator in python. This code works with the above or with is being replaced by == . Try it out (and ideally correct the answer). Thank you!!!

Comment: and in python you don't finish a statement with `';'` ;)